# Strange bug with INT/LONG conversion when using Spark GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

New developer in Scala here and also a new user of Spark GraphX.
So far, I'm really enjoying my time but I've just had a really strange bug. I have isolated the problem to a long-to-int conversion but it's really weird.
Another weird thing is that it works fine in Windows, but doesn't work in Linux (creates an infinite loop) I have located the source of the problem in Linux but I don't understand why there is a problem. I have to put the random number inside a variable first and then it works.

You should be able to copy/paste and execute the whole thing

Scala 2.10.6, Spark 2.1.0, Linux Ubuntu 16.04

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
  import org.apache.spark.graphx._
  import scala.util.Random

object Main extends App {

  //Fonction template pour imprimer n'importe quel graphe
  def printGraph[VD,ED] ( g : Graph[VD,ED] ): Unit = {
    g.vertices.collect.foreach( println )
  }

  def randomNumber(limit : Int) = {
    val start = 1
    val end   = limit
    val rnd = new Random
    start + rnd.nextInt( (end - start) + 1 )
  }

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Simple Application")
    .setMaster("local[*]")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val myVertices = sc.makeRDD(Array((1L, "A"), (2L, "B"), (3L, "C"), (4L, "D"), (5L, "E"), (6L, "F")))

  val myEdges = sc.makeRDD(Array(Edge(1L, 2L, ""),
    Edge(1L, 3L, ""), Edge(1L, 6L, ""), Edge(2L, 3L, ""),
    Edge(2L, 4L, ""), Edge(2L, 5L, ""), Edge(3L, 5L, ""),
    Edge(4L, 6L, ""), Edge(5L, 6L, "")))

  val myGraph = Graph(myVertices, myEdges)

  //Add a random color to each vertice. This random color is chosen from the total number of vertices
  //Transform vertex attribute to color only

  val bug = myVertices.count()
  println("Long : " + bug)
  val bugInt = bug.toInt
  println("Int : " + bugInt)

  //Problem is here when adding myGraph.vertices.count().toInt inside randomNumber. Works on Windows, infinite loop on Linux.
  val g2 = myGraph.mapVertices( ( id, name  ) => ( randomNumber(myGraph.vertices.count().toInt) ))

 //Rest of code removed



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're looking for a solution or the underlying reason.
I believe that `mapVertices` method is interfering with the `count` (one is a transformation and one is an action).

The solution will be

```
val lim = myGraph.vertices.count().toInt
val g2 = myGraph.mapVertices( ( id, name  ) => ( randomNumber(lim) ))
```